# How to Read the wait time value from dictionary (Excel)

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
```

I need to change the above code for selecting the `time (100)` from dictionary. 
   I need to set the value in the excel as high medium and low. 
   How to change the 
   above code on my requirement. Please help me on this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the time from a dictionary you can use the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionaryFromExcel = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"High", 400},
            {"Medium", 100},
            {"Low", 50}
        };

driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dictionaryFromExcel["Medium"]);
```

To read values from an Excel file look at this : [C# and read values from an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437595/c-sharp-and-read-values-from-an-excel-file)

Comment: Bunch of Thanks Koen.

Comment: Mark the post as the answer please.